# How to convert multiple Next.js pages to customs domains (hosted on Vercel)

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13, custom-domain, nextjs-rewrites

I would like to redirect Next.js page to a custom domain:

Example :
For the `https://domainzzz.com/user/josh`, Josh would like his page to be access by `https://joshwebsite.io`

For the `https://domainzzz.com/user/bob`, Bob would like his page to be access by `https://fannythebeauty.co`

For the `https://domainzzz.com/user/yann`, Yann doesn't want a custom domain so nothing changes.

How to do that on the fly (like Super.so) with Next.js and Vercel?

Thanks

Comment: Check https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/platforms-starter-kit. It answers everything about that.

Comment: OMG !!! @paulogdm Thank you very much ! You can add your answer so I can checkmark it!